# How can I run gradle apps in background in Gitlab job (nohup is not working in gitlab)

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, nohup

I want to run few gradle apps that will run as background processes for around 5 minutes (there will be more commands to be run after calling gradle apps and then the job will be finished). They execute just fine on my ubuntu machine using nohup:

```
nohup gradle app1 > nohup1.out 2>&1 &
nohup gradle app2 > nohup2.out 2>&1 &
...
```

Running these commands does not require pressing INTERRUPT button or enter and so I can just run multiple gradle applications in background in row and start interacting with them.

Though today I learned that Gitlab runner cancels all child processes, thus making nohup useless in a Gitlab CI job.

Is there a workaround so that I can run multiple gradle jobs inside Gitlab job in the background?
I tried using tool *at* but it did not bring functionality as *nohup* did.

Comment: `making nohup useless in a Gitlab CI job.` nohup is useless in a gitalb ci job, because there is no terminal to send HUP signal, not because of process group beeing killed. `I can run multiple gradle jobs inside Gitlab job in the background?` What is the purpose of the "gradle jobs"? Are you implementing _application deployment_? which gitlab executor are you using? Can't you just run `gradle app1 app2` with `org.gradle.parallel=true` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk Im starting up multiple gradle apps so that I can run a test for their functionality as the next step. I am not sure about the executor question. I created a Dockerfile and set up a gitlab container ubuntu image with various libraries which I am then supplying to Gitlab runner.

Answer (score 1):

To background a job, you do not need to use `nohup`, you can simply use `&` at the end of a command to 'background' it.

As a simple example:

```
test_job:
  image: python:3.9-slim
  script:
    - python -m http.server  & # Start a server on port 8000 in the background
    - apt update && apt install -y curl
    - echo "contacting background server..."
    - curl http://localhost:8000
```

And this works. The job will exit (closing the background jobs as well) after the last `script:` step is run.

Be sure to give enough time for your apps to start up before attempting to reach them.

Comment: This worked on my ubuntu machine, but in the gitlab job it ran the gradle tasks successfully and shortly after turned them off. I checked the PIDs with gradle --tasks and they were all stopped by gitlab at the end of script unfortunately.

Comment: @PedroGonzalez `stopped by gitlab at the end of the script` -- what exactly is the problem there? Is there any reason to keep background tasks going after the job has no more commands to run? Or are the tasks stopping early unexpectedly due to some error? Maybe consider checking the out file or not redirecting output.

Comment: The gradle application was shut down almost immediately after next command was issued in the pipeline, my only explanation is that gitlab runner does not like background processess. I gave up on this solution and redirected running the gradle applications on an other party server.